# How do I add multiple pages to my html website in notepad?

Tags: html, image, directory, notepad

I am trying to code a simple html/css website on notepad, without using any other tools. I know how to link a page, and add a image, but I don't know how to have multiple pages in the first place...I also don't know how to add images. The Internet obviously can't access files and images that are just sitting on someones computer, so how do I put them all together? W3schools talks about how you can link other pages in a site, but what defines "site"? Do they all have to be in a single folder? And if so, how is that folder put on the internet? I hear people talking about a directory, but I dont know what that means...Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all! So really, all the files just have to be in the same folder? And opening index.html will automatically include the others?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow :)

First you have to have multiple html files in the same folder and then just do something like  `<a href='second_page.html' >Other page</a>`

for adding an image you should have an image in the same folder and do

`<img href='image.jpg'>` or from a website using `<img href='example.com'>`

Finally for having your website on the internet you will use a software such as nginx or apache

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain the process step by step. Hope it will help you.

First Create your main page with name 'index.html" (for example).
Now add whatever you want in it. And also add a link of another page like this :
`<a href='another_page.html'> Next Page </a>`
Now create another new file in notepad with name "another_page.html" in the same folder where "index.html" is placed. Add what ever you want in the page.

Now check it in browser. Open "index.html" and click in "Next Page". Your "another_page.html" will be opened now.

For the image, suppose you have 2 images named "image1.jpg" and "image2.jpg" in the same folder with the html files. You want to place "image1.jpg" in "index.html" and "image2.jpg" in "another_page.html".
You will write this code in "index.html":
`<img href="image1.jpg">`

And write this in "another_page.html":
`<img href="image2.jpg">`

Now "image1.jpg" will be displayed in "index.html" and "image2.jpg" will be displayed on "anotger_page.html"

All names are taken for examples. You can use whatever name you want. 
Hope it will help you.